# Run Pytest on Glue

Tags: pytest, aws-glue, amazon-data-pipeline

How do I invoke pytest on aws glue ? something like below

`python -m pytest -m reg -ra --myxml=./myout.xml`

I couldn't find much info on how to pass these markers while invoking pytest. Only option I see on aws glue is to pass .py file. I am also able to pass double hyphen parameter myxml but not sure for single hyphen one like -m and -ra. I tried using python shell as well as Spark.

Answer (score -1):

```
 pytest -rA -m reg --myxml=./myout.xml
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please explain how do I add these single dash params in my glue job ? Also, where do I mention pytest ? All I can see is script location which take .py file path not the command

Comment: do pytest --help and you will get all options, -rA is for showing extra summary, -m for markers defined. create pytest.ini and add there to avoid mentioning these arguments every time

Comment: not sure if you got it wrong but this question is for AWS GLUE platform. I see what you saying but Glue configurations are bit different. are you on the same page?